# Is there any way to simulate what parts of maps api v2 are going to fail after May 19th

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The web page I use is written for api v2 and I am assuming it will stop working on May 19.
I'm just a beginner with google maps and do not have the skill set to know which parts of the scripts are going to fail.

I HAVE looked at the on line documentation for [REMOVING CODE](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3#obsolete_code) but can't find anything like: it was done **that** way before, but now it's done **this** way.

**Question:**
In order to focus my limited skills, is there any way to simulate which parts of my api v2 script are going to fail after May 19?
.. that way at least I might know where to begin to look.

Look at this simple page -->>
**[Old V2 Script](http://www.eldoradocountyweather.com/current/misc/google-maps/dax/ridge.html)**<<-- this is what I need converted to api v3.
There are two referenced .js scripts that will also need tweaking.

I found parts of my script that use "gUnload" and know that's going to fail but have no clue on what to replace it with.
Can someone look at the 3 pages and easily tell me what else going to break?

or.. are their any professionals or experts here "for hire" willing to take on the task of converting a v2 to a v3?

I know this is a "newbie" question..
..thanks in advance for your patience.

Dennis

Comment: simply assume that none of the V2-code will work anymore.

Comment: when your phone-provider tells you, that he quits the contract to May 19, do you ask if you still can call you mother after that day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about how to simulate which parts of api v2 are going to fail after May 19th.

The answer is by changing from the old google api script type to the google api script in the html.

Something like this:
old api 2 way
YOUR KEY
new api 3 way

After you do that, you will see all the old api v2 calls that are now "undefined".

but .. still looking for someone who can assist with the conversion.

Dennis